# My Oauth2-proxy pod does not receive or redirect traffic

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, openshift, keycloak

I have a simple static HTML website running in a Nginx pod on Openshift (aka Kubernetes) that I want to secure using an Oauth proxy (I followed [this guide](https://linuxera.org/oauth-proxy-secure-applications-openshift/)), and Keycloak as a SSO provider. But if I browse to my website I get nothing (*The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint.*) and if I look in the container logs of `oauth2-proxy` I don't see anything coming in:

```
[oauthproxy.go:166] OAuthProxy configured for Keycloak Client ID: documentation
[oauthproxy.go:172] Cookie settings: name:_oauth2_proxy secure(https):true httponly:true expiry:168h0m0s domains: path:/ samesite: refresh:disabled
```

I've been stuck on this for a week now, so I thought maybe you can see something simple I'm over-looking.

Deployment of html page and oauth2-proxy:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: oauth-documentation
  namespace: documentation
  labels:
    name: oauth-documentation
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: documentation
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: documentation
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: documentation-page
          image: de.icr.io/moddsp/documentation_page
          ports:
            - name: doc-auth
              containerPort: 8080

        - name: oauth-proxy
          image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest
          args:
            - --provider=keycloak
            - --client-id=documentation
            - --client-secret=
            - --login-url=https://keycloak.bla.bla/auth/realms/dsp/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            - --keycloak-group=admins
            - --session-store-type=cookie
            - --cookie-secure=true
            - --cookie-secret=
            - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
            - --email-domain=bla.bla
          ports:
            - name: oauth-proxy
              containerPort: 4180
              protocol: TCP
```

Route definition

```yaml
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: documentation-authenticated
  namespace: documentation
  labels:
    name: oauth-documentation
spec:
  host: >-
    documentation-authenticated.bla.bla
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: oauth-documentation
  port:
    targetPort: proxy
  tls:
    termination: reencrypt
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
```

Service that the route points to:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: oauth-documentation
  namespace: documentation
  annotations:
    service.alpha.openshift.io/serving-cert-secret-name: documentation-tls
spec:
  ports:
    - name: proxy
      port: 4180
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: oauth-proxy
    - name: documentation-page
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: documentation
  selector:
    name: documentation
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

So I'm thinking either:

1. the Route does not point to the Service
2. the Service does not point to the *oauth2-proxy* Deployment
3. the Deployed *oauth-proxy* is somehow misconfigured

But I can't see anything wrong with any of the three.
Can you help me fix the configuration so that the oauth is reachable?

Comment: Perpexity.ai suggesed changing http-address="0.0.0.0:4180" to ":4180" but that didn't change anything

Comment: Did you try hardcoding the 'targetPort: 4180'?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the Service selector seems wrong: you are targeting a deployment by using

```
selector:
    name: documentation
```

which means you are looking for a target deployment/pod with a label
section that looks like this

```
labels:
  name: documentation
```

and not like this

```
  labels:
    name: oauth-documentation
```

So, maybe you can try to change the deployment label and see if something changes?

Comment: I did, but nothing changed sadly.

Comment: did what? changed the selector or the deployment labels?